# [fake_pi_robot.launch] is neither a launch file in package [rbx1_bringup] nor is [rbx1_bringup] a launch file name

Tags: roslaunch

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm using groovy on ubuntu 12.04. rbx_vol_1 is a package I downloaded through svn checkout http://ros-by-example.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/rbx_vol_1 ,then I rosmake it ,there is no failures existing. In order to ensure that the package can be visible in my ROS package path,I run rospack profile after rosmake rbx_vol_1. then I launch the note :roslaunch rbx1_bringup fake_pi_robot.launch ,error occurs,[fake_pi_robot.launch] is neither a launch file in package [rbx1_bringup] nor is [rbx1_bringup] a launch file name.
Please help me ,thank you in advance!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/152436/%5Bfake_pi_robot.launch%5D-is-neither-a-launch-file-in-package-%5Brbx1_bringup%5D-nor-is-%5Brbx1_bringup%5D-a-launch-file-name/) by [danmianjing_00](https://answers.ros.org/users/14196/danmianjing_00/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2014-04-13

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2014-04-13**:
rospack profile does NOT add packages to the ROS package path. As the build succeeded I'm assuming that you already did that. Given that: Is fake_pi_robot.launch a launch file in package rbx1_bringup? What do you get for rospack find rbx1_bringup?

**Comment by [lyshello123](https://answers.ros.org/users/30150/lyshello123/) on 2017-04-25**:
I met the problem that is the same with you.Please ask you how to solve this problem.Please help me ,thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Have you place rbx folder on one of the ROS_PACKAGE_PATH ? If yes, then you should try source all the setup.bash again.

To check whether or not your package can be seen by roslaunch, you should try this in the terminal

```
export | grep ROS
```

This is the PATH output for me and my rbx1 package is in `/home/ros/catkin_ws/src`

```
ROS_PACKAGE_PATH="/home/ros/catkin_ws/src:/opt/ros/groovy/share:/opt/ros/groovy/stacks"
```

---

Originally posted by [Maya](https://answers.ros.org/users/12786/maya/) with karma: 1172 on 2014-04-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0